# Deciphering a C++ Backtrace

Tags: c++, backtrace

Can someone point me as to where I might find an explanation for decoding/deciphering a backtrace. There are thousands of links that explain how to read a dump file, a call stack within an IDE, or creating a backtrace. So where is the one for "I was given a backtrace in an email for a previously internally released code, but nothing explaining why"

i.e. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x350e0) [0x7f58aa6a80e0]

I have been given a backtrace from a crash that occurred once. So I am trying to determine why there was a crash and fix so the it gracefully continues. I have no explanation of what the user was doing, what the system was supposedly doing or anything just the backtrace.

I am not trying to find an issue in the above line it is just the example of a backtrace line. Now what I do know from the example above.

The line states that a line of code in libc.so.6 was called, that the line of code can be found at 0x7f58aa6a80e0 within the code segment of the binary. Problem here is that the code segment address is not returned using addr2line since the address in not in the viewable range (symbols removed). What again does the +0x350e0 represent and how do I use?
I know the exact function that the crash occurred in, not the line.

This is not a solution but a WT.
Best I can tell from a little reverse engineering of the code.

Recompiled libtsm_sl with the added flags -Xlinker -Map=object.map
Found the Address for both AssignReservationSlots and GenerateSOL in object.map.
Then
objdump -D libtsm_sl | less

Then searched the output for AssignReservationSlots+0x5ec which I found. At 558481
Also searched for the address for the call from GenerateSOL and got that address. At 55a480

Now from the stack trace in the log file

```
4)  /usr/lib/libtsm_sl.so.0(AssignReservationSlots()+0x5ec) [0x7f58ae415490]
5)  /usr/lib/libtsm_sl.so.0(GenerateSOL()+0x87d) [0x7f58ae417485]
```

I took the [value] and found the delta which is 0x1FF5, subtracted that from the address for in the libtsm_sl for GenerateSOL’s call to AssignReservationSlots and the resulting address comes to fall on the line in the objdump that has AssignReservationSlots+0x5ec

7f58ae417485 - 7f58ae415490 = 1ff5

55a480 – 1ff5 = 55848B

558481 is line 1449 in NCClass.cpp 
55848B is also 1449. It is an if statement and refers to the second argument on the line which is just a bool variable.

So we crashed on evaluating a bool????

Now what??? No answer needed, its rhetorical.

Comment: How did this person generate the backtrace?  If it's from some tool (e.g., breakpad), then that tool would provide a lot more information.

Comment: Application received a SIG_ABORT, this then called the signal handler which in turn generated the backtrace. All internal to the application. Why sig-abort was generated is the big question...

Comment: Generally the bug that caused the crash is not going to be in libc. Go back up the stack to find where your code called into the stack, then try to map that to one of your functions and A) inspect the hell out of that function and B) pray that the bug that caused the crash wasn't on the far side of Pluto, the program ran for another few days or years, and then finally crashed. A Stack trace can only tell you where to start looking. In a complicated program you are one lucky son of a <expletive deleted> if a stack trace leads you directly to the bug.

Comment: Side note: If you have the whole trace, you might as well add it to the question. It's better than nothing, and currently just north of nothing is what you've given us to work with.

Comment: Like I said in the original, I know the last function before calling into libc. All symbols have been removed so know which line number I was on is now unknown from the backtrace, unless there is a way to take the [value] and reverse it into the binary with symbols. My backtrace is 25 lines, and the libc is just line 3. Not really looking for what the root problem is just is there a way to reverse or decode what i have in the backtrace

Comment: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x350e0) [0x7f58aa6a80e0]` `AssignReservationSlots(unsigned int&, unsigned char&, unsigned int)+0x5ec) [0x7f58ae415490]`

Comment: I can rebuild the code to what was for this release. Again the question that appears to be missed in all this is... Is there a way to reverse the [0x7f58ae415490] or +0x5ec to something useful if I can build the code with symbols.

Comment: If you use `-Xlinker -Map=output.map` when you compile the code it will write all the addresses of all the functions used to a file.  I don't know if that includes the libc ones or not.